# Writing data from multiple list box into excel columns in c#

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, csv, file-writing

I have a windows form application in c# where there are list of data in multiple listbox (around 56 in each listbox). 
here is an example:

1. listbox1 contains data of name of students
2. listbox2 contains data of address of students
3. listbox3 contains percentage of students.

the list goes on with the student data.
Now i need to print the data in excel in a button click event.
the data should go in an ordered way .

I tried using the CSV helper but it only helped me for 1 set of list box i need to sent data from multiple list box.

```
var sw = new StreamWriter(@"output.csv");
var csvWriter = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(sw);

foreach (var Name in lbx.Items)
{
    csvWriter.WriteField(Name);
    csvWriter.NextRecord();
}
foreach (var Address in ptr.Items)
{
    csvWriter.WriteField(Address);
}
sw.Flush();
```

However, this doesn't solve the problem.  Any help regarding the solution to this problem would be helpful.
Any other method to solve the problem will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult for me to determine the full details of your configuration, but if it's as simple as two `ListBox` controls for which you're writing values, you could easily do something like the following:

```
var sw = new StreamWriter(@"output.csv");
var csvWriter = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(sw);
int lbxCount = lbx.Items.Count;
int ptrCount = ptr.Items.Count;
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Max(lbx.Items.Count, ptr.Items.Count); i++)
{
    object lbxValue = lbxCount > i ? lbx.Items[i] : String.Empty;
    object ptrValue = ptrCount > i ? ptr.Items[i] : String.Empty;
    csvWriter.WriteField(lbxValue);
    csvWriter.WriteField(ptrValue);
    csvWriter.NextRecord();
}
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```

This determines the maximum number of records to write (`Math.Max(lbx.Items.Count, ptr.Items.Count`) based on the greatest `ListBox.Items.Count`.

By altering your loops to be a single loop, you can now use the `WriteField` method correctly. If the `ListBox lbx` does not contain a value for a certain record, it uses a `String.Empty` as the value for that record. Likewise it does the same for `ListBox ptr`, in the event that there are more items in `lbx`.

If you have many `ListBox` controls on a single form and wish to each of them, you could determine the maximum items overall by iterating through all `ListBox` controls and getting their respective `Item.Count` values as follows:

```
var sw = new StreamWriter(@"output.csv");
var csvWriter = new CsvHelper.CsvWriter(sw);
int maxRecords = 0;
List<ListBox> listBoxes = new List<ListBox>();

// Add all ListBox controls to list
// Determine maximum number of items (in all ListBox controls)
foreach (Control control in Controls)
{
    if (control.GetType() == typeof(ListBox))
    {
        ListBox currentListBox = (ListBox)control;
        listBoxes.Add(currentListBox);
        if (currentListBox.Items.Count > maxRecords)
            maxRecords = currentListBox.Items.Count;
    }
}

// Write fields for each ListBox
for (int i = 0; i < maxRecords; i++)
{
    foreach (ListBox currentListBox in listBoxes)
    {
        if (currentListBox.Items.Count > i)
            csvWriter.WriteField(currentListBox.Items[i]);
        else
            csvWriter.WriteField(String.Empty);
    }
    csvWriter.NextRecord();
}
sw.Flush();
sw.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for exactly and a small query  what if there are multiple number of ListBox could you please make it clear.

Comment: @kamalpandey: If you have multiple `ListBox` controls and you would like to iterate through each of them, you could easily use this by iterating through `Controls` and finding all controls that have a `ListBox` type. Then you can determine the maximum number of records (`maxRecords`) and change your `csvWriter` to loop through each accordingly. I've edited my answer to include this generic solution.